# How to mutate an object without duplication?

Tags: javascript, object

I have this object

```
var originalObj = {
  shop: [
    { id: 1, list: "buy milk", complete: false},
    { id: 2, list: "buy bread", complete: false}
  ]
}
```

I would like to change the first item to `complete: true`

```
var newObj = Object.assign({}, originalObj, {
  ['shop']: [
    {...originalObj['shop'][0]
      complete: true}, ...originalObj['shop']
  ]
})
```

The problem with this is that the `newObj` ends up with three objects, where the one I am trying to edit gets duplicated.

Comment: Is there more to your underlying problem than meets the eye?  Why not just `originalObj.shop[0].complete = true`?

Comment: @JamesThorpe but I do not want to change the original object

Comment: This is because you are adding the whole shop array back in, after you add this object {...originalObj.shop[0], complete: true}

Comment: @inoabrian I did add `...originalObj['shop']` in front and the end result is the same (but different order), when I remove that I just get the new edited object alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deep copy may have issues sometime. Object.assign() copies the property reference when the property being assigned is an object. It is better you can use the following method.

```
var originalObj = {
  shop: [
    { id: 1, list: "buy milk", complete: false},
    { id: 2, list: "buy bread", complete: false}
  ]
};
var newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalObj));
newObj.shop[0].complete = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

My Comment : "This is because you are adding the whole shop array back in, after you add this object {...originalObj.shop[0], complete: true}"

The ...originalObj.shop is spreading the whole array.
so you have this

```
[{the newly edited object with complete = true}, ...originalObj.shop] 
...originalObj.shop looks like this : 
[{ id: 1, list: "buy milk", complete: false},
{ id: 2, list: "buy bread", complete: false}]
```

In my answer I filter the "old" { id: 1, list: "buy milk", complete: false} out.

```js
var changeObject = function(index, objectToEdit){
   var newObject = {}; 
   newObject = Object.assign({}, originalObj.shop[index]);
   newObject.complete = true;
   return newObject;
};

var originalObj = {
  shop: [
    { id: 1, list: "buy milk", complete: false},
    { id: 2, list: "buy bread", complete: false}
  ]
}; 

var changedObj = changeObject(0, originalObj);
var unchangedObjs = originalObj.shop.filter( sobj => {
   if(sobj.id != changedObj.id)
    return sobj;
});

var newObj = {
  'shop': [
    changedObj,
    ...unchangedObjs
  ]
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj));
```

Just noticed my answer completely avoids the solution you wanted.
So here is the solution you want:

```
 var newObj = {
  'shop': [
    {...originalObj.shop[0], complete:true},
    ...originalObj.shop.filter(so => {return so.id != originalObj.shop[0].id})
  ]
};
```